# problem in updating installation

Tags: 14.04, 16.10

I am getting the following error message after updating:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try :  sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you provided, I would recommend that you open a terminal, and run the command `sudo apt-get install -f`.  This should look like the following:  [image]